# IIS losing Custom Sessions even despite all App_pool recycling settings set to FALSE

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, iis-7.5, session-state

We have an aspx.net application with IIS 7.5 and we are facing a huge problem as this application is losing or abandoning sessions for no clear reason. Due to client restrictions we must use Custom Sessions instead IIS Sessions.

The Application Pool is using Pipeline : Integrated and Framework is 4 and all the ‘Recycling’ settings in the Application Pool has been set to FALSE.

The Customer Session I am talking about is a .cs class we created based on an example suggested by Microsoft here on how to create custom Sessions. The only thing we did different from this Microsoft example is that we added another session variable named ‘Token’ and every time we need to check for the session id.. we also check if the token exists. As you can see is a matter of simple validation.. but again, seems like IIS is discriminating this token session.

When we trace the application using Fiddler it reveals the token ID is empty however the session ID value still exists.. so I doesn’t make sense at all.

If it is someone who can give us an advice and tip or maybe has been on a similar issue and tell us what it was done to overcome the issue we really, really appreciate that help.

Please help

Comment: sounds like you should use `HttpContext.Current.Session["yourSessionObject"]` and Initialize it in the Global.Asax file under the Session_Start event

Comment: Is it possible that it's recycled due to the default idle setting? It came as a suprise to me too that there is more recycling settings in the advanced settings of the app pool. http://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/cc771956(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

A few things I would check:

- Check for log entries in the windows event logs under system for app pool recycling (usually under WAS as a source) as it's possible that the app pool is still recycling unbeknownst to you
- In the global.asax application_start create a public static DateTime which captures when the app pool starts and write the variable out as a header in the Application_BeginRequest event to help make sure the app pool isn't recycling.  Sometimes the recycles are very transparent and you may not be noticing them.
- You can store the session state outside of the app pool in a few other places such as:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178586(v=vs.100).aspx  The state server and sql server will keep the data even if the web server restarts.
- Is it possible that something is causing the session IDs to change when they shouldn't be? Making it seem like the session is being lost?